# Remove max value from simply-connected list

Tags: c++, stack

How can I can remove max value from a Simply-Connected list?

Two of the solutions I tried produce wrong results. Please explain to me what am I doing wrong. With code, if not difficult.

**Stack:**

```
struct Stack
{
    int info;
    Stack *next;
} *top;
```

**Wrong solution 1:**

```
void delMaxValue(Stack **stck, int maxValue){
Stack *tmp = NULL;
do {
    if ((*stck)->info != maxValue) 
        tmp = *stck;
        cout << tmp->info << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    *stck = (*stck)->next;
} while ((*stck)->next != NULL);
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    *stck = tmp;
    *stck = (*stck)->next;
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

**Wrong solution 2:**

```
Stack* deleteMaxValue(Stack *begin) {
Stack *t = begin, *p = begin->next;
for (; p; p = p->next)
    if (p->info > t->info)  t = p;
p = begin;
if (p != t) {
    while (p->next != t)   p = p->next;
    p->next = t->next;
}
else
    begin = t->next;
delete t;
return begin;}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, Ron

Comment: You seem to rearrange **all** the pointers instead of only the deleted node. Walk the links until you find the value you are looking for. Then change **one** pointer `prev->next = this->next;`. Now `this` has left the list and can be disposed of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

struct Stack
{
    int info;
    Stack *next;
    // added just to easy initialization
    Stack(int _info, Stack *_next) : info(_info), next(_next) {}
} *top;

void delMaxValue(Stack *&head) 
{
    // first - find MaxValue in the list
    // as you can see, i save pointer to the previous element in the list
    Stack* max_prev = nullptr;
    Stack* max = head;
    for(Stack *i_prev = nullptr, *i = head; i; i_prev = i, i = i->next) {
         if (max->info < i->info) {
             max_prev = i_prev;
             max = i;
         }
    }
    // max has the maximum value and max_prev is the element before max in the list
    // now we remove max
    if (max_prev == nullptr) {
        // max has no prev, so max is the head of the list. We assign the new head
        head = max->next;
     } else {
        max_prev->next = max->next;
        max->next = NULL;
     }
}

void printStack(Stack *head) {
    std::cout << "Priting " << head << std::endl;
    for(Stack *i = head; i; i = i->next) {
        std::cout << i << " " << i->info << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack *head = new Stack(1, new Stack(15, new Stack(10, nullptr)));
    printStack(head);
    delMaxValue(head);
    printStack(head);
    return 0;
}
```

You may interest yourself in list helping macros from bsd, now available in glibc, newlib, openbsd etc., see [here](https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/misc/sys/queue.h).

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution takes maximum value as a parameter, while the second one doesn't. I am assuming we don't have the maximum value and will calculate it while processing the stack.

The basic approach should be to think of a logic first.

Step 1.) We need to pop all the elements to find the maximum element in the stack. Also, we need to store all the values we popped in another stack(say, *auxiliary*). Now, we are aware of the maximum value(say *MAX*).

Step 2.) Note we would have the stack in reverse now. Pop all elements from the auxiliary stack and if the value is not max, push them in the original stack.

Data Initially,

```
Original Stack: 1->2->3->4->100->5->7->NULL
Auxiliary Stack: NULL
```

Data after first Step,

```
Original Stack: NULL 
Auxiliary Stack: 7->5->100->4->3->2->1->NULL 
MAX: 100
```

Finally,

```
Original Stack: 1->2->3->4->5->7->NULL
Auxiliary Stack: NULL
```

Try to code for this. Your both solutions are doing things way differently than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I hope It will be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>

struct LList
{
    int info;
    LList *next;

    //constructer
    LList(int info_) :info(info_) {
        next = nullptr;
    }
};
void removeMaxValue(LList *&root) {
    int max = 0;

    LList *temp = root;
    //Searching for max value
    while (temp!=nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->info > max)
            max = temp->info;

        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = root;
    //Find max value and remove
    while (temp->next->info != max)
        temp = temp->next;

    LList *maxNode = temp->next;

    temp->next = temp->next->next;

    delete maxNode;
}
void print(const LList *root)
{
    while (root!=nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << root->info << " ";
        root = root->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    LList *root = new LList(15);
    root->next= new LList(10);
    root->next->next= new LList(45);
    root->next->next->next = new LList(85);
    root->next->next->next->next = new LList(5);

    //before removing
    print(root);

    removeMaxValue(root);

    //After removing
    print(root);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions take two different approaches. I chose the one where the function doesn't know what actual max value is so it has to find it first.

First, the function just iterates through the elements and chooses the max value.
Then it searches for the first node that contains this value and removes the node.

```
void stackRemoveMaxValue(Stack*& top) {
    if(top == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    // Find max value.
    int maxValue = top->info;
    Stack* node = top->next;
    for(; node != nullptr; node = node->next) {
        if(maxValue < node->info) {
            maxValue = node->info;
        }
    }

    // Remove first node that contains maxValue.
    Stack* previous = nullptr;
    Stack* current = top;
    do {
        if(current->info != maxValue) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        } else {
            if(previous != nullptr) {
                previous->next = current->next;
            } else {
                top = current->next;
            }
            delete current;
            return;
        }
    } while(current != nullptr);
}
```